# SQL query with tuples in Python

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, tuples

I have a dict like this:

```
{
    '05_23': '[L]',
    '05_22': '9:39',
    '05_21': '9:37',
    '05_20': '9:34',
    '05_27': '14:41'
}
```

I take the keys and values from it and create lists:

```
keys = list(d.keys())

print keys
['05_23', '05_22', '05_21', '05_20', '05_27']

values = list(d.values())

print values
['[L]', '9:39', '9:37', '9:34', '14:41']
```

And then I construct this SQL query with it:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO table {} VALUES {}".format(tuple(keys), tuple(values)))
```

Which results in the following error:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO table {} VALUES {}".format(tuple(keys), tuple(values)))

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "table": syntax error
```

And I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: `table` is a SQL keyword.  You want the table name there.

Comment: What is your table name? Here is an example of SQL insert -  `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);` you need to replace table_name with the name of your table

Comment: Can this be done? `c.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (X) VALUES (:X)", d)`

Comment: Thanks guys... that hand't occured to me...

Answer (score 1):

`table` is not a valid table name. See [the list of SQLite keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

> The SQL standard specifies a huge number of keywords which **may not be used as the names of tables**, ...

Comment: Wow... that didn't occur to me.

It works fine now. Thanks!